# ordinary differential equations solution needed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find   non-trivial solution $y$  of BVP    $$y''+xy=0,  x\in [a,b],$$ $$y(a)=y(b)=0.$$
Till time no method which i know works. Please help some one.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations) method should fit!

Comment: You know power series?

Comment: $\large y'' - xy=0$ is the [equation for the Airy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of $[ \partial_{x} + k^{2} x ] y = 0$ is
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{ \sqrt{x} }{3} \left[ A J_{-1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ x^{2/3} \right) + B J_{1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ x^{2/3} \right) \right].
\end{align}
The conditions $y(a) = y(b) = 0$ lead to
\begin{align}
A = - B \frac{J_{1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ a^{2/3} \right) }{ J_{-1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ a^{2/3} \right) },
\end{align}
for the case of $y(a)=0$. Now the case of $y(b)=0$ yields
\begin{align}
0 = B \left[ J_{-1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ a^{2/3} \right) J_{1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ b^{2/3} \right) - J_{1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ a^{2/3} \right) J_{-1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ b^{2/3} \right) \right]. 
\end{align}
From this equation either $B=0$, which implies $A=0$ and $y(x)=0$, or $B \neq 0$ which then says that $a$ and $b$ are connected by the equation
\begin{align}
J_{-1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ a^{2/3} \right) J_{1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ b^{2/3} \right) = J_{1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ a^{2/3} \right) J_{-1/3}\left( \frac{2k}{3} \ b^{2/3} \right).
\end{align}

This differential equation is well known and has a good description here 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html